# Unicode underline does not completely underline some characters

Tags: string, unicode

I have a `string` in a C# application that needs to be underlined.  This needs to be done in unicode as the string is exported and displayed in a word file.  To do this I preceded every character with the underline unicode `\u0332`which works, but it does not completely underline the 'm' character as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

I have tried preceding the `\u0332` a few times before the m and after but the output is always the same.

Is there any way to get it to completely underline the character?

EDIT: I just tried using the continuous underline unicode symbol `\u2381` but that does not render at all.

Answer (score 5):

U+0332 is a Unicode [combining character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), so ist goes **after** the character that it modifies. But this only specifies that the character should be underlined. The specific graphical representation depends on the application and its rendering engine; it's not fully supported everywhere. Try to paste the text `i̲m̲p̲o̲r̲t̲a̲n̲t̲` into the application and see if it works as intended. If not, then there is nothing you can do, except using another representation such as `*important*` or `IMPORTANT`, or exporting in a supported rich text format (RTF, docx, etc.).

Comment: Thanks.  It's an MS Word .docx document, which I would think support this and render it properly.  I'm kind of at the mercy of it since the application looks through a templated document for tags encased in `< >` brackets and replaces them with the contents of the correspondingly named `string` variable in the application.

Comment: Why are you using Unicode hacks to *format* something in a Word document?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Trust me, this is not an ideal situation - It's a legacy application and it's the first time this request has come up.  For example, The templated Word document just has something akin to `<results>` and the application goes through and replaces `<results>` with the information contained in the `results` string from the application, in which one word contained in the string is to be underlined.  This is done at runtime so there's no way to format the text within the template itself, it needs to be formatted on the application side.